# python spacebar not recognized

Tags: python, bash, macports, miniconda

My problem is that when I run a python version obtained through macport or Miniconda from the bash the **spacebar is not recognized in the python shell**. When I press the spacebar I just hear the beep sound.

Using different shell does not seem to solve the problem.

This does NOT happen when I compile Python from source or when I used the python already installed in the system. I am running OSX 10.9.5. I compiled different python version and they work fine so it does not seem to be related to the version of python I am using.

And it happen only with python/ipython I have never seen this problem with other application or in my bash.

It seems to be **something related to how Macport (and Miniconda) python is compiled** (maybe some libreadline issue?). I also tried the Miniconda version and that shows the same problem.

Some possible info are:

Tha miniconda version has the problem

```
    otool -L ~/miniconda/bin/python2.7
/Users/alessandromanzotti/miniconda/bin/python2.7:
    @loader_path/../lib/libpython2.7.dylib (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 476.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

As well as the macport python

```
otool -L /opt/local/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python:
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

otool -L /opt/local/bin/python3.3
/opt/local/bin/python3.3:
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Python (compatibility version 3.3.0, current version 3.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

The osx python installed with the systems works

```
otool -L /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.14.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

As well as the 2 version I compiled

```
otool -L /Users/alessandromanzotti/Python2.7.8/bin/python2.7 
/Users/alessandromanzotti/Python2.7.8/bin/python2.7:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.17.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2577.0.0)
```

Comment: How are you launching the Python shell?

Comment: Not sure python shell is the right way to call it. Anyway just from the terminal lunching the bin. /usr/bin/python2.7 for the system version of python /opt/local/bin/python for the macport version.

Comment: Thanks, I think that information will be key to the solution. I don't have a solution, mind you, but I think that information will end up being importing.